# Python https requests runs on python3.9 but crushes on python versions above 3.9

Tags: python, https, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm sending some code to a server which has a soap api and a self signed certificate according to firefox.
I'm using this code this works only in python 3.9:

```
url="https://ws.hph.hu:10446/v1b/OrderInfos.svc"
message="""soap xml"""    
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = {}
headers={"Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
"SOAPAction":"soap-action",
"Expect":"100-continue",
"Connection":"Keep-Alive"}
r=s.post(url,data=message,headers=headers,verify=False)
```

if i delete the `verify=False` parameter in python 3.9 i get this error `Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)`
if i run the code in 3.10 or any whersion above 3.9 i get the following error with or without `verify=False`:
`[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the openssl version in python 3.10 and 3.11
I still not know what it is but
Changing the ssl version solves the problem

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl
import requests
class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
   '''An HTTPS Transport Adapter that uses an arbitrary SSL version.'''
   def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
       self.ssl_version = ssl_version

       super(SSLAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

   def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
       self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                      maxsize=maxsize,
                                      block=block,
                                      ssl_version=self.ssl_version)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://',SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1))
r=s.post("https://ws.hph.hu:10446/v1b/OrderInfos.svc",verify=False)
```

Credits: https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/